# Content ignoring max-width when within a Flexbox container in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Wondering if anybody else is experiencing the following and either found a solution or may have suggestions.

The code below renders correctly on Chrome (35.0.1916.153), but it does not on Firefox (Firefox 29.0.1):

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://g.twimg.com/business/page/image/11TwitterForSmallBusiness-300_1.png"/>
</div>
```

A runnable example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jc3A3/16/

Comment: could you explain better what are you trying to achieve? By the way your fiddle has errors in css rules

Comment: @Chris - It's not CSS. It's SCSS. Accepted by Fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Add `min-width: 1px;` to the `.container`.

https://ntucker.true.io/ntucker/solution-firefox-34-ignoring-max-width-for-flexbox/

Answer (score -2):

try separating the `img` from your `.container`

eg:

```
.container {
--your style here
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```